# Bokeh Line chart not plotting complete pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, bokeh, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure if this is an issue because charts are currently being updated in Bokeh but I can no longer plot a complete dataframe using Line charts from Bokeh in my Jupyter notebook. Using [this example from the docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.8.1/docs/user_guide/charts.html):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Line
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_file
from bokeh.charts import Chart, Line
xyvalues = OrderedDict(
    python=[2, 3, 7, 5, 26, 221, 44, 233, 254, 265, 266, 267, 120, 111],
    pypy=[12, 33, 47, 15, 126, 121, 144, 233, 254, 225, 226, 267, 110, 130],
    jython=[22, 43, 10, 25, 26, 101, 114, 203, 194, 215, 201, 227, 139, 160],
)

# any of the following commented are valid Line inputs
xyvalues = pd.DataFrame(xyvalues)
#xyvalues = xyvalues.values()
#xyvalues = np.array(xyvalues.values())

output_file("lines.html", title="line.py example")
chart = Line(xyvalues, title="Lines", ylabel='measures', legend=True)
show(chart)
```

I get: [Incorrect dataframe plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrlXW.png) which is clearly different to the example shown in the docs.

If I explicitly give the dataframe an index and pass all the columns like below then it gives the expected plot:

```
xyvalues = pd.DataFrame(xyvalues, index=range(14))

output_file("lines.html", title="line.py example")
chart = Line(xyvalues, y=['python', 'pypy', 'jython'],
             title="Lines", ylabel='measures', legend=True)
show(chart)
```

My notebook specs:

> You are using Jupyter notebook.
>
> The version of the notebook server is 4.0.6 and is running on:
>   Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
>   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
>
> IPython 4.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: This might be a bug. It's  hard to say without know, e.g. what version of Bokeh you are using. Can you come by the GH issue tracker and make an issue there so that the core devs can see this? https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: What version of `bokeh` are you using? It works as expected for me with `0.11.0dev2`

Comment: @Jake I did `import bokeh` `bokeh.__version__` and got `'0.10.0'`.

Comment: @bigreddot Issue created here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3371

Answer (score 2):

Updating to `0.11.0dev4` through conda fixed the issue.

```
conda install -c bokeh/channel/dev bokeh
```